# Setting '.mat-progress-bar-fill::after' using document.querySelector

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want to dynamically set the progress bar fill value or Angular Material Progress Bar

I'm able to do this in CSS using:

```
::ng-deep .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Because the CSS value needs to be dynamically set, I cannot do that within the CSS

I have tried to use - `(document.querySelector('.mat-progress-bar-fill::after') as HTMLElement).style.background = 'green';` but that generates an error of `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`

It is possible though to use the same code to set the background colour using - `(document.querySelector('.mat-progress-bar-buffer') as HTMLElement).style.backgroundColor = 'red';`

So the questions seems to be how do I select `.mat-progress-bar-fill::after` using `document.querySelector` or at least how do I set the fill bar dynamically from within an Angular component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The before and after pseudo elements are not in the DOM so Javascript doesn't know about them. But you can use CSS variables and set those in the actual element and they will get picked up by the pseudo element.

e.g. in the CSS:

```
::ng-deep .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
  background-color: var(--bg);
}
```

and in the JS:

```
document.querySelector('.mat-progress-bar-buffer).style.setProperty('--bg', 'red');
```

Comment: I had to make a small modification to your code so it became this:

`(document.querySelector('.mat-progress-bar-fill') as HTMLElement).style.setProperty('--bg', value)`

But it works now. I had no idea it was possible to pass in dynamic values to CSS. I thought that was a SCSS thing only

Thank you a lot for your time!